# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python

```
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
import vk_api
from datetime import datetime
import random

vk = vk_api.VkApi(token="token")
session_api = vk.get_api()
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk)
for event in longpoll.listen():
         if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            print('Сообщение пришло в: ' + str(datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%H:%M:%S")))
            print('Текст сообщения: ' + str(event.text))
            print(event.user_id)
            try:
                messages = vk.method("messages.getConversations", {"offset": 0, "count": 20, "filter": "unanswered"})
                if messages["count"] >= 1:
                    id = messages["items"][0]["last_message"]["from_id"]
                    body = messages["items"][0]["last_message"]["text"]
                    if body.lower() == "привет":
                        vk.method("messages.send",
                                  {"peer_id": id, "message": "Привет!", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
                    elif body.lower() == "каола":
                        vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "каола", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
                    else:
                        vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Не понял тебя!",  "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
```

Comment: `else` не может быть без `if`, код очевидно некорректен

Comment: @andreymal messages = vk.method("messages.getConversations", {"offset": 0, "count": 20, "filter": "unanswered"})
                if messages["count"] >= 1:
                    id = messages["items"][0]["last_message"]["from_id"]
                    body = messages["items"][0]["last_message"]["text"]
                    if body.lower() == "привет":
                        vk.method("messages.send",
                                  {"peer_id": id, "message": "Привет!", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
                    и тд

Comment: Код должен быть в тексте вопроса, а не в комментариях. И без «и тд», а достаточно полный, чтобы воспроизводить проблему

Comment: @andreymal кинул

Comment: @andreymal кинул фото

Comment: `try` не может быть без `except`, код снова стал очевидно некорректен

Comment: Всё,сработало. Спасибо